# Keypad freezes for few seconds

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext

In one of my activities within an app, there is an EditText. When the android keypad comes up and the user starts typing on it, it freezes for about 5-10 seconds, and when the keypad is closed, it shows a part of different activity for about 5-10 seconds. I am unable to find the reason behind this anomaly. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: update anr logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of Android's theme. I had set the theme as:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent".
```

I changed to a different theme and its working fine now.